# Pages module error on channel form submission

Tags: safecracker, pages

I am getting this notice error while submitting channel entry form.

```
Notice
Undefined index: pages__pages_uri
ee/EllisLab/Addons/pages/tab.pages.php, line 155
```

Although, all entry data being saved with no "Pages URI".

I am using EE v5.3.2.

Comment: Please provide additional information such as your EE version, what first and third party add-ons are installed, what infrastructure you are running on (Linux vs. Windows? Apache vs nginx? PHP version? MySQL version?), etc... And do you actually use the Pages module? If so, to what degree? Are you trying to save a Channel Entry that has a Pages routing?

Comment: @jrothafer sorry, I forgot to mention and thanks for your comment here. I always try participate in conversation :) and answered some questions asked here.

Comment: Is the entry you are trying to save routed in the Pages module?

Comment: @jrothafer sorry not sure if I am getting your question but yes, I have setup channel into Pages setting by associating template with the channel.